# Converting column to/from hex in PySpark using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame (converted from PySpark RDD using .toDF) that contains a few columns of data.  One column contains values in hex format, eg.:

```
+----------+
|        id|
+----------+
|0x0087AFEE|
|0x00840190|
|0x0082F4D3|
|0x00871A60|
|0x00850A0E|
|0x0084557C|
...
```

In another DataFrame I have the same ID, but in decimal values, which I want to join with this column.  I assume I need to convert these values to base 10 decimal first (or vice versa) in order to compare.  How can I accomplish this?

I tried:

```
    df.withColumn('dec_id', sf.conv(df['id'], 16, 10))
```

but this gives back 0's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `0x` using `substring` (note that string index starts from 1):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('dec_id', F.expr("conv(substring(id, 3), 16, 10)")).show()
+----------+-------+
|        id| dec_id|
+----------+-------+
|0x0087AFEE|8892398|
|0x00840190|8651152|
|0x0082F4D3|8582355|
|0x00871A60|8854112|
|0x00850A0E|8718862|
|0x0084557C|8672636|
+----------+-------+
```

Note that the result is in string type. If you want to have int/long type, you can cast accordingly, e.g.

```
"int(conv(substring(id, 3), 16, 10))"
```